# Convert Relational Database Model to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need guidance in how to properly set up a MongoDB collections/documents structure given the following relational database model:

**Cases**

- Id: number
- Name: string

**Attorneys**

- Id: number
- Name: string

**CaseAttorneys** (which Attorneys are assigned to this case)

- Id: number
- CaseId: number
- AttorneyId: number

**TimeEntries**

- Id: number
- CaseId: number
- AttorneyId: number
- Date: date
- Description: string
- Amount: number

## Example Scenario:

Attorney 0 and Attorney 1 are assigned to Case 0 in CaseAttorneys.  Attorney 0 and Attorney 1 each bill an item on Case 0 in TimeEntries.

**Sample TimeEntries Data**

1. 1st Record

   - Id: 0
   - CaseId: 0
   - AttorneyId: 0
   - Date: 12/18/2017
   - Description:  Review documents
   - Amount:  100.00
2. 2nd record

   - Id: 1
   - CaseId: 0
   - AttorneyId: 1
   - Date: 12/18/2017
   - Description:  Discuss issues with Attorney 0.
   - Amount:  230.00

## MongoDB:

What is the best way to set up the structure for collections/documents/subdocuments in MongoDB in order to use simple, built-in queries to get, for example:

- All Attorneys Assigned to Case 0 (2 attorneys)
- All TimeEntries for Case 0 (2 entries)
- All TimeEntries for Attorney 1 (1 entry)

What collections would you make?  What do the documents for each collection look like?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: That was a helpful link.  I wanted to read Part 3 and couldn't find it.  It turned out the author, William Zola, died very shortly after he wrote Part 2.  Wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by setting up the DB in the same way that the RDB was set up, and use [Document References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) to map out your relationships. Document references can easily be populated (similar to a join) when you perform your query.

The above guide helps you to think through how to organize your references. Consider where it says "the growth of the relationships determine where to store the reference". In most cases, you would probably want to follow the last example on the page.

Comment: I thought there would be something more "awesome," about NoSQL.  To me, it appears to be suitable for the same tasks as RDB with the difference that it can embed objects.  Before MongoDB, size: {height: 1, length: 2, width: 3} was simply stored as height: 1, length: 2, width: 3.  This so-called "document" approach almost begs new users to succumb to the temptation to denormalize their related data, which should be done only as described and with a good understanding of the drawbacks.  Documents which need to stand-alone in collections should not be embedded but should be referenced.  Easy.

Comment: The two things that I find really helpful are: 1. the queries are JSON-like and easy to integrate into your code if you're already writing JavaScript. 2. Handling those one-to-few relationships. It's super easy to just throw in an array wherever you need one, and on subsequent queries you automatically pull everything you need without a join. (Arrays can be stored in other RDB's of course but it's just not as "native" and quick and easy to me.) I use arrays often when I know I'll only ever need them in the context of the whole document.